# how to iterate over cassandra row one by one using python?

Tags: python, cassandra

Lets say i have a table in cassandra like now this has one million rows and i want to scan all the rows one by one using python or in batches of 50 as i have to migrate to some other database say sql.how to scan each row?

```
  CREATE TABLE emp(
     emp_id int PRIMARY KEY,
     emp_name text,
     emp_city text,
     emp_sal varint,
     emp_phone varint
);

from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect()
session.set_keyspace('users')
Row=  session.exexute(   select * from emp)
for row in Row:
     //Do something
```

The Above example fetches all the rows from Cassandra database.
As the number of rows can be large,it  can cause Memory issues while executing the select statement.is there any way to iterate the rows one by one

Answer (score 0):

You need to use query paging. The Datastax's Python driver for Cassandra has this feature. More details [here](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/query_paging.html).